# Vis.js timeline onMoving throws an error

Tags: javascript, gwt, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

I am trying to get a callback for onMoving on my timeline but keep getting the error:

> "(Error) : option onMoving must be a function onMoving(item, callback)"

This is what I am trying to do

```
options.onMoving = function (item, callback) {console.log('onMoving')};
```

For other things like snap this works without any problem

```
options.snap = function(date, scale, step) {
    var hour = snapTimeMinutes * 60 * 1000;
    return Math.round(date / hour) * hour
}
```

How can I fix this error?

Other events I am not doing on the options object, but on the items like the following code, but this does not seem to work for `onUpdating`.

```
itemsJS.on('update', function (event, properties) {
});
```

I cannot directly declare the options JSON since I am wrapping the code in GWT. And I cannot put functions inside an object...

Additional information:

What I am trying to achieve is using the `onMoving` callback from options. Like in this JS example : view-source:http://visjs.org/examples/timeline/editing/editingItemsCallbacks.html

In my wrapper I created a Java Options object like.

```
public class Options
{
   private boolean moveable = true;
   private boolean showCurrentTime = false;
   ....
}
```

Then I create in java such an Options object and set the correct parameters.

Then in my wrapper I convert the Options object to a JSON string using GWTJackson.

And finally in a JSNI method I do the following :

```
var options = JSON.parse(optionsJson);

if (snapTimeMinutes != 0)
     options.snap = function(date, scale, step) {var hour = snapTimeMinutes * 60 * 1000; return Math.round(date / hour) * hour} //I can still add parameters in the jsni method to the JS Options object, but if I try this with onMoving I get the error specified in the beginning of this post

timeline = new $wnd.vis.Timeline(container, itemsJS, groups, options);
```

This all works no problem with normal fields like boolean, string, int, float, ... But I don't know how I can add that `onMoving` thing, since it is a function.

Comment: Why can't you declare the options JS object in GWT? JsInterop makes that easy, and even pre-JsInterop you can do that with JSOs (though it is a bit ugly).

Comment: Well... Maybe GWT can do it. But I can't figure out how. Never used JsInterop, and I did not found a solution with JSNI. Any pointers on where to look of how to let it work with JSNI ?

Comment: Change the question to document the options format you need and the JS you'd ideally like to have, and I'd be happy to provide an answer showing the equivalent Java that GWT will compile to that JS.

Comment: Added some extra information to the question

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
selectable: true,  
editable: {
    updateTime: true,
},
```

to your options.

The documentation says `onMoving` is
*Only applicable when both options selectable and editable.updateTime or editable.updateGroup are set true*